# Accessing items in a JSON object for fetch requests

Tags: json, backend, put, json-server

I am using json-server as a mock backend databas. The file looks like this:

`{ partners: [{"id": "partner1", "configurations": [list of objects]},`

`{"id": "partner2", "configurations": [list of objects]}]}`

That repeats for two other categories.

I want to be able to change values in the objects in configurations through PUT requests but I do not know what url to use to accesss it. If I use the url `http://localhost:3000/partners/partner1` I do not get the isolated list of objects and cannot update them. And urls `http://localhost:3000/partners/partner1/configurations` and `http://localhost:3000/partners/partner1.configurations` do not work either.

Does anyone know of a way to access just the list of objects through a url for a fetch command?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) works best when the structure of your JSON file is normalized - in a similar way you'd store this in SQL DB. For example, this is how your data might be reorganized:

```
{ 
  "partners": [ { "id": "partner1" }, { "id": "partner2" } ],
  "configurations": [{
    "partnerId": "partner1",
    "foo": "bar",
    "bar": "foo"
  }, {
    "partnerId": "partner1",
    "foo": "bar2",
    "bar": "foo2"
  }, {
    "partnerId": "partner2",
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "bar"
  }]   
}
```

... and so on. With this structure, json-server will be able to resolve requests like this:

```
http://localhost:1111/partner/partner1/configurations
```

... by 'joining' the pieces of data from different properties of the first level of the document. This approach is something [recommended by](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/359) by the module's author, [typicode](https://github.com/typicode).